# Passing javascript variable to popup DIV

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I have a HTML main page with a DIV for popup. When user click a button in the main HTML page, hidden value is collected by javascript. and then javascript open the popup. Can the value collect by javascript to be sent to the popup?

In the following code, the value apple need to be display by echo $abcd.

```
<div class="pages">
<input type="button" name="addQuestion" value="click" /> 
<input type="hidden" value="apple" name="cellname" />
<div>

<div class="popup" id="popupid">
<?php
echo $abcd;
?>
<div>
```

Java script

```
 var cell = document.getElementsByName("cellname");
    for (var i = 0; i < cell.length; i++) {
        cell[i].strcell = cell[i].value;
        cell[i].onclick = popupMenu;

    }

function popupMenu() {  
    var abcd = this.strcell;  // need to send this value to popup div.
    document.getElementById("popupid").style.display = 'block'; 
 }
```

Comment: why not just pass it through the function? `function popupMenu(abcd)` and `cell[i].onclick = popupMenu(cell[i].strcell);`

Comment: you want to use `this` context with in your code, check the answer.

Comment: Would your suggestion take the variable to the popup div? does it have any affect on (document.getElementById("popupid").style.display = 'block';) Simply variable should pass from main html to javascript, back to main html (popup DIV)

Comment: It does not need to take it will be automatically passed.

Comment: But if your inputs are hidden how are you going to click them?

Comment: I will make it visible. It was just an example. exciting to see html to java to html... Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell me how to call the function by (cell[i].onclick) ? Sorry for my ignorance about some basics.

Comment: Hey  codehx, have you deleted your answer?